# Socket Android não sai do while, por que?

Tags: java, android, socket

Após mandar o evento tenho que fechar o programa para mandar outro evento pelo socket. Percebi que ele não esta fechando, fica preso no `while` papos passar pelo `publichProgress(response);`
Na verdade quando entra no `buffData = is.read( buff, 0, 2048 );` ele pausa a thread.

SOCKET

```
   protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress( host, port );
        socket = new Socket();                                Log.i( "Status : ", "Openning socket");
        socket.connect( sockaddr, timeout );
        publishProgress( "Start Connection... " );            Log.i( "Start Connection... ", "" );
        socket.setOOBInline( true );                          Log.i( "Tcp receiver ", "" );
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            publishProgress( "CONNECTED" );                   Log.i( "Status : ", "Connected to Server " + host + ":" + port );
            is = socket.getInputStream();                     Log.i( "Get data : ", "Receiving response from Server..." );
            os = socket.getOutputStream();                    Log.i( "Send data : ", "Send data to Server..." );
            for (String p : params) {
                os.write( p.getBytes() );
            }
            os.flush();
            byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
            int buffData = is.read( buff, 0, 2048 );

            while (buffData != -1) {
                String response = new String( buff );
                // Envia os dados para Main
                publishProgress( response );                Log.i( "Get data : ", "Buffer from response..." );
                buffData = is.read( buff, 0, 2048 );
            }
        }else{
            publishProgress("CONNECT ERROR - Disconected ");
        }
    } catch(ConnectException e1){
        publishProgress( "ERROR CONNECTION" );         Log.e( "SocketAndroid :", "Network is unreachable - End for timeout.", e1 );
        result = true;
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        publishProgress( "ERROR CONNECTION" );         Log.e( "SocketAndroid :", "input and output error", e2 );
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception e3) {
        publishProgress( "ERROR CONNECTION" );         Log.e( "SocketAndroid", "Generic error", e3 );
        result = true;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();                             Log.i( "ImputStream : ", "close" );
            }
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();                             Log.i( "OutputStream : ", "close" );
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();                         Log.i( "Socket : ", "close" );
                publishProgress( "DISCONNECTED" );      Log.i( "Socket : ", "DISCONNECTED" );
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {                         Log.e( "SocketAndroid", "Error closing connection - ", e );
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

MainActivity

```
  private void startSocket() {
    if (servidor1.isEmpty() && servidor2.isEmpty()) {
        Snackbar.make( btnPanico, "Verifique as configurações do seu app.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG ).setAction( "Action", null ).show();
        return;
    }
    if (count <= (atemptcount / 2) && !servidor1.isEmpty()) {
        server = servidor1;
    } else if (count >= (atemptcount / 2) && !servidor2.isEmpty()) {
        server = servidor2;
    }
    // try {
    String txtenviando = getResources().getString( R.string.enviando );
    txtSucess.setText( txtenviando );
    // Recupera host e porta
    String hostPort = String.valueOf( server ).trim();
    int idxHost = hostPort.indexOf( ":" );
    final String host = hostPort.substring( 0, idxHost );
    final int port = Integer.parseInt( (hostPort.substring( idxHost + 1 )) );
    // Instancia a classe de conexão com socket
    st = new SocketTask( host, port, 5000 ) {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... progress) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
            // Recupera o retorno
            txtStatus.setText( sdf.format( new Date() ) + " - " + progress[0] );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            exibirProgressbar( true );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute( aBoolean );
            exibirProgressbar( false );
            Log.i( "onPostExecute : ", "passou" );
        }
    };
    String dados = ("#" + conta + "," + phoneNumber + "," + latitude + "," + longitude + "," + evento + "," + status + "," + DataTime + "$");
    st.execute( dados );

    }
```

Uma tentativa foi desta maneira :

```
            int len=1;
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[len]; // len é o tamanho da resposta esperada
            int total = 0;
            while (total < len)
            {
                byte[] objectAsByte = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                int pctsize = is.read(objectAsByte);
                System.arraycopy(objectAsByte, 0, receivedBytes, total, pctsize);
                total += pctsize;
            }
            if(receivedBytes.length != -1){
                String response = new String(receivedBytes);
                publishProgress( response );
            }
```

Comment: "quando entra no buffData = is.read( buff, 0, 2048 ); ele pausa a thread" - o método `read()` é bloqueante, se ele não leu toda a quantidade de bytes solicitada ele pausa a thread para aguardar I/O. Você tem que fazer um controle de quantos dados ele deve ler ou talvez definir um caracter de parada.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo? não sei onde implemetar e nem como esse controle.

Comment: Bom, bora pesquisar na internet read() e como ele se comporta...

Comment: Ta dificil entender, alguém tem um exemplo ? Eu espero receber um caracter "@" de retorno; Na verdade eu o recebo. O metodo já deveria ser satisfeito com isso e ir para encerramento no finish; Mas não vai.

Comment: Tentei isso mas deu loop infinito                  while (buffData != -1) {
                    String response = new String( buff );
                    // Envia os dados para Main
                    publishProgress( response );  
                    if(!response.contains( "@" )) {
                        buffData = is.read( buff, 0, 2048 );
                    }
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar getReceiveBufferSize() para saber quantos bytes tem disponível no buffer do socket antes de fazer a leitura.

```
byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[len]; // len é o tamanho da resposta esperada
int total = 0;
while (total < len)
{
    byte[] objectAsByte = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
    int pctsize = is.read(objectAsByte);
    System.arraycopy(objectAsByte, 0, receivedBytes, total, pctsize);
    total += pctsize;
}
```

Evitando assim de mandar ele ler mais bytes do que realmente existe, e travando a thread para sempre. Caso precise de uma resposta rápida, você pode implementar um `timeout` para sair do `while` se os dados não chegarem a tempo.

Comment: Resolveu. Talvez por ser apenas um caracter "@" de retorno o is.read deve esperar uma string maior, não ?

Comment: E a propósito. Porque sempre que faço uma pergunta recebo  -1 ? Mas o que que tem de errado na minha pergunta ? Tinha desistido desse forum a um tempo a traz, porque sempre me fazem isto. E não tenho com quem falar sobre isso. Sabe o quanto é chato to aqui me esforçando peço ajuda e recebo este tipo de coisa. Chato isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado Christian Beregula pela ajuda. Obrigado mesmo.